# OROPlateform Error : Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework, orocrm

I am installing ORO-Plateform on my windows system. I download the package from its official site and put it in the xampp/htdocs folder. While i run this command "***composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev***". I am getting below error.

> Problem 1
>   - Installation request for zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.5 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-i18n[2.1.5].
>   - zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.

How can i resolve this? Please help me. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Is there any special reason to downvote my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error `zendframework/zend-i18n` requires `intl` php extension to be installed. This extension is bundled with PHP as of version 5.3.0, so open `php.ini` and uncomment `;extension=php_intl`.

Also, take a look at the installation guide [php.net Intl Installing/Configuring](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php)